# Multi-webapp Maven 2 project -- how to build a single webapp?

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, maven, multi-module

I have the following source layout:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── modules (has pom)
│   ├── module1 (has pom) 
│   └── module2 (has pom)
│   └── moduleN (has pom)
└── webapp1 (has pom)
└── webapp2 (has pom)
```

webapp1 and webapp2 depends on all of the modules (the modules being DAO, services, etc).
At the moment, I build everything from the root and `mvn package` gives me two WAR files.

How do I build only webapp1 or webapp2?

If I `cd` into webapp1 and run `mvn package` it says it can't download moduleX.jar (this is with a clean repository). Surely Maven should be able to deduce that those modules need to be built first as dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I build only webapp1 or webapp2?

Use ["advanced reactor options"](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/). From the root:

```
mvn install -pl webapp1 -am
```

This tells maven to install `webapp1` and the projects on which `webapp1` depends (in the right order).

The help (`mvn -h`) documents these commands like this:

```
-pl, --projects
        Build specified reactor projects instead of all projects
-am, --also-make
        If project list is specified, also build projects required by the list
```

<strike>Note that you need to invoke `install`, dependencies are always resolved through the local repository (so you need to `install` them).</strike> I was wrong, calling `package` does work (I don't know how/why, but it does).

Comment: Pascal, if I clear my packages from my local (rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/com/mycompany) and then run mvn -pl webapp1 -am package, then the repo stays the same, i.e. my JAR files aren't copied to local. This is actually a nice side-effect, but does this counter what you said about having to "install"?

Comment: *I clear my packages from my local (...) and then run mvn -pl webapp1 -am package, then the repo stays the same* Yes, `package` doesn't `install` to the local repository (but why are you "messing" with the local repository?). *This is actually a nice side-effect, but does this counter what you said about having to "install"?* Wow, I just double checked on a pet project and you're right, calling `package` only works. I wasn't aware of this (and I don't understand why/how it works).

Comment: I was "messing" with the local just to check what side-effects each phase has. Thanks for your help, Pascal :)